# 2-D array multiplcation with N-D array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two array X and Y. I am trying to find:

```
0.5x0 0.25x1 0.125x12 0.0625x3 0.03125x4
```

and so on for other rows of X. Multiply values in Y(starting from 1st index) to values in each row of X.

So output array should be same size as X. Was wondering if there was any built in function available to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the `*` operator, and slice `Y[1:]` to drop the first element

```
>>> X * Y[1:]
array([[0.     , 0.25   , 1.5    , 0.1875 , 0.125  ],
       [2.5    , 4.     , 0.875  , 0.5    , 0.28125],
       [0.     , 2.75   , 1.5    , 0.8125 , 0.125  ],
       [7.5    , 4.     , 2.125  , 0.5    , 0.59375],
       [0.     , 0.25   , 1.5    , 0.1875 , 0.125  ],
       [2.5    , 4.     , 0.875  , 0.5    , 0.40625],
       [2.     , 3.75   , 0.     , 0.3125 , 0.     ]])
```

Comment: I could not use * since they have different shapes (7,5) (5,1)

Comment: Using the exact `X` and `Y` in your example I pasted verbatim what python output using `*` operator. When you try this, what error do you get?

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,5) (5,1)